# WordPress save_post not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the below code (edited to reduce size) that is not working as intended. The update_post_meta is not updating.
It does nothing if I have it the way it is, but if I uncomment the last 2 lines and print out the results, followed by die;, then the function works and update_post_meta works, and updates the custom field.

Any ideas??

```
function swd_add_time_as_line_item($post_id) {

$invoice_id = $post_id;
$title          = $_POST['time_tracker_add_title'];
$description    = $_POST['time_tracker_add_desc'];
$qty = '1';


// store the data in array
$arr = array("swd_billing_qty" => $qty, "swd_billing_title" => $title, "swd_billing_description" => $description, "swd_billing_amount" => '75' );

// get existing tasks, if they exist. will simply be empty if none exist
$existing_items = get_post_meta($invoice_id, 'swd_billing_item', true);

// add the array data to existing data, or simply adds it if there is none
$existing_items[] = $arr;

// update the post meta
update_post_meta($invoice_id, "swd_billing_item", $existing_items);

// pp($existing_items);
// die;

}
add_action('save_post', 'swd_add_time_as_line_item', 10, 1);
```

**SOLVED**
I added the following code to the bottom of the function and it is now working.

```
$update = update_post_meta($invoice_id, "swd_billing_item", $the_items, $existing_items);

if($update == true) {
    wp_safe_redirect('post.php?post=' . $invoice_id . '&action=edit&message=4');
    die;
}
```

Comment: Wordpress is not PHP, even though it may run on the language.

Comment: try print_r on the variables to see what they are set to.

Comment: Sorry, the pp(); function is my shorthand function for print_r. So when I print out the variables, it is all correct and the function saves the post meta. But when I don't print it out it doesn't save.

Comment: Post you solved your own question in an answer box, not in the question itself.